# NULL values in codeigniter from POST

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, post, null

UPDATE:

```
    Error Number: 42S22/1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `attendance` (`event_date`, `event_time`, `event_info`, `player_id`, `is_present`, `notes`) VALUES ('2017-03-08', '11:00:00 AM', 'other', NULL, Array, 'notes')
```

'NULL' should be the 'player_id' and 'Array' should be either present or absent. Very stuck on this so thank you for all of your help so far I really appreciate it.

I'm trying to create an attendance table which will hold a person's id and then have two columns - 1 to make for present and the other to mark for absent. So I would be adding multiple rows to the database in one go.

I've just added code from the view because I know my controller and model is fine as the other input fields are working fine.

For every row I want it to input the `player_id` and whether they were `present` or `absent`. In my database it is an enum `yes` or `no` for is_present. I know this is probably no where near correct so thanks for any suggestions.

```
<div class="container-fluid">  
<div class="form-group"> 
        <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-md-6">
          <h2 class="brand-before text-center"></h2>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered tabular_datable-condensed table-hover" id="playertable" name="player_id"> 

  <tr>
  <th>Player ID</th>
  <th>Player first name</th>
  <th>Player surname</th>
  <th>Add</th>
  </tr>

   <tr class="clickable-row">

<?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['player_id'];?></td>

        <td><?php echo $row['player_first_name'];?></td>

        <td><?php echo $row['player_last_name'];?></td>

<td align="left">
 <label>
 <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['player_id']; ?>]" value="Yes" <?php echo set_radio('attendance', 'Yes', TRUE); ?> >Present
 </label>
&emsp;
 <label>
 <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['player_id']; ?>]" value="No" <?php echo set_radio('attendance', 'No', TRUE); ?> >Absent
 </label></td>

    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</tr>
    </table>
```

The controller

```
function add_attendance(){

    $event_date=$this->input->post('event_date');
    $event_time=$this->input->post('event_time');
    $event_info=$this->input->post('event_info');
    $player_id=$this->input->post('player_id');
    $is_present=$this->input->post('attendance');
    $notes=$this->input->post('notes');


    $data = array(
        'event_date'=>$event_date,
        'event_time'=>$event_time,
        'event_info'=>$event_info,
        'player_id'=>$player_id,
        'is_present'=>$is_present,
        'notes'=>$notes

);
```

Comment: what do you want to do with gender?

Comment: @KristjanKica sorry that's just a typo - it's attendance in the code

Comment: perhaps you want this piece of code  before you close the input tag? Not after you close the label tag <?php if (isset($attendance) && $attendance=="yes") echo "checked";?>

Comment: @KristjanKica Thanks, I changed the code - is that what you mean? or would both label closes be after the second radio box. It still doesn't seem to be working either way.

Comment: Please show your form submit? why `name="attendance[]"` as `array`? is it batch input? use `set_radio('attendance', 'Yes');` to show checked.

Comment: Your function add_attendance should be in controller

Comment: @ichadhr thank you for the reply and sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question with the changes I've made.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thanks for the answer! I did have it in there I guess I just formatted the answer incorrectly, sorry! I've made an update

Comment: By default if no value found in $this->input->post('attendance'), So that it is returning the NULL. Post your update code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered tabular_datable-condensed table-hover" id="playertable" name="player_id">
```

Please remove table attr `name=player_id`?

Here is example **view**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player ID</th>
            <th>Player name</th>
            <th>Attending</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row) : ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- hidden input for player_id -->
            <?php echo form_hidden('player_id[' .$row["player_id"]. ']', $row['player_id']); ?>
            <!-- /hidden input for player_id -->
            <td><?php echo $row['player_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['player_name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['player_id']; ?>]" value="Yes" <?php echo set_radio('attendance', 'Yes', TRUE); ?> >Present
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['player_id']; ?>]" value="No" <?php echo set_radio('attendance', 'No'); ?> >Absent
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Example]

Once submitted there is multiple arrays posted

**Controller**

```
public function add()
{
    $player_id = $this->input->post('player_id');
    $is_present = $this->input->post('attendance');

    $i=1;
    $data = array();

    // formating array posts
    foreach ($player_id as $k => $val) {
        $data[] = array('player_id' => $val, 'is_present' => $is_present[$i]);
        $i++;
    }

    echo var_dump($data);
}
```

here is output post would be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["player_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_present"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["player_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["is_present"]=>
    string(2) "No"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["player_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["is_present"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

next your model call `$this->db->insert_batch()` for [multiple insert](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

Comment: Glad it was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Fix the input

```
 <label>
 <input type="radio" name="attendance<?php echo $row['player_id']; ?>" 
 value="yes"<?php if (isset($attendance) && $attendance=="yes") 
 echo "checked";?>  > Present
 </label>
```

Comment: Thanks I changed this. I also added in my model code incase there is also a problem here as it's still showing as null values trying to be inserted in my error log.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are the inputs are get posting to the controller using `echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->input->post()); exit;` and then find the whats the problem with input. Also remove the array from the radio button.